# Magento 2 Insert data to table that contain foreign key error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: database, magento-2.1, model, foreign-key

i want to insert data to a table that contain foreign key, but it always gives me an error like this:

> [2017-01-18 04:45:51] main.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`goku`.`lime_courierservices`,
>   CONSTRAINT `FK_EDC3A7832725FC587764FA1BFF56B114` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`couriers_id`) REFERENCES `lime_courier/lime_couriers`
>   (`couriers_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
>
> Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`goku`.`lime_courierservices`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_EDC3A7832725FC587764FA1BFF56B114` FOREIGN KEY (`couriers_id`)
>   REFERENCES `lime_courier/lime_couriers` (`couriers_id`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE), query was: INSERT INTO `lime_courierservices`
>   (`courierservices_id`, `name`, `description`, `couriers_id`) VALUES
>   (?, ?, ?, ?)

i think the problem is the data that i insert is (?,?,?,?), but i already make sure by printing **$model->getData()** after **$model->setData()**, and the data was there, here's how i insert the data from model:

```
public function setCourierservices()
  {
    $model = $this->_courierserviceModel->create();
    $courierservices = $this->getCourierservices();
    foreach($courierservices as $courierservice){
      $data = array(
        'courierservices_id' => $courierservice->id,
        'name' => $courierservice->name,
        'description' => $courierservice->description,
        'couriers_id' => $courierservice->courier_id
      );
      $model->setData($data);
      try {
        $model->save();
      } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->_logger->addError($e->getMessage());
      } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->addError($e);
      }
    }
  }
```

here's how i create the table:

```
       $table_lime_courierservices->addColumn(
                'courierservices_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                array('identity' => false,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true,),
                'Entity ID'
            );
            $table_lime_courierservices->addColumn(
                'name',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                [],
                'name'
            );
            $table_lime_courierservices->addColumn(
                'description',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                null,
                [],
                'description'
            );
            $table_lime_courierservices->addColumn(
                'couriers_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                15,
                ['nullable' => false],
                'couriers_id'
            );
         $table_lime_courierservices->addForeignKey(
             $installer->getFkName('lime_courier/lime_courierservices', 'couriers_id', 'lime_courier/lime_couriers','couriers_id'),
             'couriers_id',
             $installer->getTable('lime_courier/lime_couriers'),
             'couriers_id',
             \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
        );
```

Comment: Use direct SQL query instead of Model to insert data if you are facing foreign key issue.

Comment: @BornCoder i'm avoiding using direct SQL query, because the problem is exist with other model that contain foreign key too

Comment: then setId of  foreign key when you are saving and first getData and check that your are getting foreign key in that or not

Comment: @BornCoder the data is correct when i'm doing get data

Comment: are you getting your foreign key in that ??

Comment: @BornCoder it turns out my foreign key is pointing at wrong table, because when i install table to add foreign key like this `$installer->getTable('lime_courier/lime_couriers')`, the solution is to go like this `$installer->getTable('lime_couriers')`,